# How to get recovered c# class in working order

Tags: c#, crash, data-recovery, file-recovery

I was browsing YouTube a few days ago, and my computer suddenly crashed with a PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA error. This has happened a few times, and I assume it's just a bug in Windows 10, and it never really affected me too much, as when the computer restarted all the tabs and files I had open re-opened. However, this time when my computer restarted, the error seemed to have corrupted a class I was working on using visual studio at the time (The other classes were untouched thankfully :D). The corrupted class had also created 202 errors, most of them being:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS1056  Unexpected character ' 
(the ' looked like [] in the actually error, if that helps)

I went to the class location and opened it with notepad to see what had happened to it, but the whole thing was blank (even though you could still make text selections of the blank space).

I looked online to see if anyone else had encountered this problem and someone had [this](http://www.samnoble.co.uk/2014/11/30/visual-studio-crashes-and-a-corrupted-cs-file/).
I tried all the solutions but none gave me any results except solution four (which was to download a program called recurva and run a scan on the directory that had the class in it). The recovered file had this in it:

```css
"LinkFilterHashList"
{
 "List_3"
 {
  "UpdateTime"  "1440597537"
  "version"  "8E1298389020E47C82385F70CD2D2CBFCBF16415"
  "ListHashes"
  {
   "127"  "a10b2cb9"
   "126"  "9b4b0158"
   "125"  "d51486ac"
   "124"  "90d4be26"
   "123"  "5f0339e8"
   "122"  "44bad6fd"
   "121"  "17ea1c80"
   "120"  "b7c14d80"
   "119"  "82e02475"
   "118"  "45dbfd52"
   "117"  "5112a614"
   "116"  "623c6132"
   "115"  "f15d5b67"
   "114"  "450f9de3"
   "113"  "c72f6261"
   "112"  "76db13e1"
   "111"  "d5d74942"
   "110"  "4c31aea4"
   "109"  "39be93f6"
   "108"  "f7a03d6a"
   "107"  "67ca16d3"
   "106"  "450d18ff"
   "105"  "d3ebc87f"
   "104"  "bd46a91b"
   "103"  "0afee1a3"
   "102"  "ccd92718"
   "101"  "a0244293"
   "100"  "2426f23b"
   "99"  "defe4f66"
   "98"  "55bb2e0e"
   "97"  "1560bc34"
   "96"  "d4e454db"
   "95"  "c002249a"
   "94"  "3904e93e"
   "93"  "c8d6d91e"
   "92"  "716b327f"
   "91"  "763dc014"
   "90"  "cb1a4644"
   "89"  "b4d31bce"
   "88"  "9c86f47b"
   "87"  "f6337120"
   "86"  "f0fa14d1"
   "85"  "dd1405fb"
   "84"  "4be7fd6d"
   "83"  "f0eb2085"
   "82"  "d3bf95ea"
   "81"  "e1b9b9c9"
   "80"  "a052f026"
   "79"  "ff120db1"
   "78"  "f6f73860"
   "77"  "a6f25f79"
   "76"  "5fe133bf"
   "75"  "1e9f5241"
   "74"  "2352753a"
   "73"  "932b1389"
   "72"  "7d4c0b1c"
   "71"  "ce171620"
   "70"  "a248bfee"
   "69"  "3ed688bd"
   "68"  "a2001d91"
   "67"  "6eed69b1"
   "66"  "50340073"
   "65"  "4d164331"
   "64"  "83dbdf21"
   "63"  "41c27890"
   "62"  "1918e6c7"
   "61"  "72601636"
   "60"  "5d6e0537"
   "59"  "1e5dca25"
   "58"  "bf6d9a00"
   "57"  "7a9dca5d"
   "56"  "cb094fd0"
   "55"  "9c44b858"
   "54"  "4db97899"
   "53"  "d3ffef5a"
   "52"  "1084ac47"
   "51"  "80e2567a"
   "50"  "90ae19fa"
   "49"  "3a1e0ffe"
   "48"  "74c8a2e0"
   "47"  "d142e8a9"
   "46"  "75e3b51c"
   "45"  "cbd1da13"
   "44"  "2820efab"
   "43"  "0f280c48"
   "42"  "75624871"
   "41"  "7597abfd"
   "40"  "bd0fb8a6"
   "39"  "79a7f00a"
   "38"  "5a780f42"
   "37"  "abb58601"
   "36"  "c70319d1"
   "35"  "aa387037"
   "34"  "c58bd0fc"
   "33"  "271ab389"
   "32"  "382fc066"
   "31"  "cd9e1de8"
   "30"  "87d9e083"
   "29"  "26796404"
   "28"  "f466b44e"
   "27"  "06c7b1d7"
   "26"  "cfe635e0"
   "25"  "7bf78afd"
   "24"  "57a55b2a"
   "23"  "13284911"
   "22"  "c14cc073"
   "21"  "6323fc24"
   "20"  "9f533812"
   "19"  "7c8ead73"
   "18"  "f6389d4c"
   "17"  "24ee8dd0"
   "16"  "93517ede"
   "15"  "a716c85c"
   "14"  "1f316383"
   "13"  "bcf5833f"
   "12"  "cf89c5b5"
   "11"  "46230cf9"
   "10"  "35970855"
   "9"  "397ad2e1"
   "8"  "57e6e7bc"
   "7"  "5b1f58cb"
   "6"  "c2734de0"
   "5"  "ece2b91b"
   "4"  "67e1603d"
   "3"  "ba8e5ae7"
   "2"  "4d3846f1"
   "1"  "f6064fb3"
   "0"  "8f4887b3"
  }
 }
 "List_6"
 {
  "UpdateTime"  "1440597538"
  "version"  "2551A1522AEA2CF617641A9D53264DE41C06D773"
  "ListHashes"
  {
   "85"  "60872dd8"
   "84"  "62bf4267"
   "83"  "44e0f55a"
   "82"  "71cf1e3d"
   "81"  "d368c87c"
   "80"  "635d0396"
   "79"  "9eec3af5"
   "78"  "29f7defc"
   "77"  "4a99fe0b"
   "
```

I also saw that text in the header of the file in recurva, along with this:

```css
22 4C 69 6E 
6B 46 69 6C 
74 65 72 48 
61 73 68 4C 
69 73 74 22 
0A 7B 0A 09 
22 4C 69 73 
74 5F 33 22 
0A 09 7B 0A 
09 09 22 55 
70 64 61 74 
65 54 69 6D 
65 22 09 09 
22 31 34 34 
30 35 39 37 
35 33 37 22 
0A 09 09 22 
76 65 72 73 
69 6F 6E 22 
09 09 22 38 
45 31 32 39 
38 33 38 39 
30 32 30 45 
34 37 43 38 
32 33 38 35 
46 37 30 43 
44 32 44 32 
43 42 46 43 
42 46 31 36 
34 31 35 22 
0A 09 09 22 
4C 69 73 74 
48 61 73 68 
65 73 22 0A 
09 09 7B 0A 
09 09 09 22 
31 32 37 22 
09 09 22 61 
31 30 62 32 
63 62 39 22 
0A 09 09 09 
22 31 32 36 
22 09 09 22 
39 62 34 62 
30 31 35 38 
22 0A 09 09 
09 22 31 32 
35 22 09 09 
22 64 35 31 
34 38 36 61 
63 22 0A 09 
09 09 22 31 
32 34 22 09 
09 22 39 30 
64 34 62 65 
32 36 22 0A 
09 09 09 22 
31 32 33 22 
09 09 22 35 
66 30 33 33 
39 65 38 22 
0A 09 09 09 
22 31 32 32 
22 09 09 22
```

(I know that isn't technically code but it in a snippet for easier reading).

I assume that it is possible to turn these bits of text back into c# but I'm not sure how. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. (Btw, I know about the visual studio backups but it doesn't seem to have created a backup of any of my files).

*EDIT*: I would provide a screenshot of recurva but It doesn't seem to work after I tried using chkdsk /f to fix the issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll look into those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Recovering files

Crashes like that can happen at any time due to many reasons. The NTFS file system does not guarantee the recoverability of files. If it is possible, then that's just luck.

With the file contents you mentioned in your question, it's not possible to get the C# code back. As you can see, the first data is just text (looks like JSON) and the second is exactly the same, just displayed as hexadecimal values.

### The real solution

You should really look into a version control system like [SVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) and a Windows Explorer integration like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) and a Visual Studio integration like [VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/).

Any other version control is fine as well (Git, TFS, Mercury, CVS, Bazaar), just choose one which fits your needs.

Those will not only help in case of crashes, they will also help if you changed your code, saved it intentionally and you find out the code just doesn't work.